Alice splits the bill not too generously with Bob
Alice and Bob go out for dinner and the restaurant bill is 100€. Beforehand, they had agreed to evenly pay half of the bill, but suddenly Alice is in a bit of a generous mood and offers Bob a probabilistic opportunity to pay less than half.
Alice tells Bob: I have a 100 bit number in mind (i.e.: a number between 0 and 2100-1). She also tells Bob how many bits in the binary representation of the number have value 1.
Alice challenges Bob: You may try to guess the number I have in mind by guessing each of its bit values one by one in any order you like, and, for each guess I will reveal the bit value. As such I will gradually reveal more and more about the number I have in mind. If you guess clever, you can, on average, correctly guess almost 60% of the bit values. I propose to pay the amount of bit values you turn out to be able to correctly guess.
So if, for example, Bob correctly guesses 55 bit values of the 100 bit number, he pays only 45€ and she pays the rest.
What is the smallest number Alice can have in mind? That is, for every smaller number, Bob can, on average, correctly guess more than 60% of the bit values. i.e.: Alice is generous, but not too generous, a bit stingy.
I apologize for late edit:

 I had planned to, one day, give credit to @quarague for puzzle Guesstimate a multiple choice exam which was my inspiration for this puzzle. Thanks @quarague! See perhaps my answer Guesstimate a multiple choice exam to spot the logic. However, I did not want to do so day-1 in order to not influence people searching for answer. But meanwhile dust has settled over this puzzle which is more then one month old, I think it is time to give credit now.


Suppose Alice tells Bob there are 45 ones in the number.  Does she choose a random subset of size 45 of the 100 digits to be ones, and the rest zeros?  If we don't know the probability distribution Alice uses to choose the bits, I feel we cannot make sense of Bob's expected win probability.

@TylerSeacrest it doesn't matter how Alice chooses her number, as long as she genuinely has chosen one before Bob starts guessing and doesn't change it. Bob can just randomise his strategy to reduce to the uniform case, and he can't do any better in general since Alice could have chosen it uniformly.

@EspeciallyLime:  I don't think it's so simple.  Suppose Alice chooses 59 zeros followed by 41 ones.  Using the accepted answer's strategy, Bob doesn't correctly guess "more than 60%".  Of course, if Bob chooses a different strategy he could get 100%, but that's true for any specific number Alice chooses.  Is this a game between Alice and Bob and we're looking for the Nash equilibrium?  The accepted answer certainly doesn't prove both players are using an optimal strategy.  How does Bob randomize his strategy to guarantee "over 60%" with 41 ones?

@TylerSeacrest : It was not my intention to let A and B play a game and find a balance. Sorry if my question was not clear about that. The percentages are averages and the order of bits actually does not matter neither for A constructing nor for B guessing. Your comments are likely inspirational for a better puzzle :)

@TylerSeacrest that's why Bob needs to randomise: he follows the accepted strategy except he guesses bits in a random order. This is equivalent to applying a random permutation to the bits of Alice's number, which (no matter what number she chose) turns it into a uniformly random number with the same number of 1s.

@EspeciallyLime oh that makes sense.  I totally forgot Bob could guess out of order.  That is the Nash Equilibrium then.

@EspeciallyLime : Bob does not really need to randomize. He can, but does not need to, guess in any order (and Alice could have arranged in any order as well, but does not need to). The numbers are averages.  As for equilibrium: non cooperating Alice and Bob both can try to improve strategy by reorder to no avail in terms of (average) payoff.

@FirstNameLastName Well in order for an average to be meaningful someone (either Alice or Bob) needs to randomise. My point was simply that it doesn't matter who.

Alice must choose a number with no less than

 42 bits set

The lowest such number is

 $2^{42}-1$ = 4,398,046,511,103

Bob's strategy is:

 Keep track of how many ones are left. If more than half of the remaining bits are 1, guess 1, otherwise guess 0.

If we do this, then the score Bob can earn is defined by the following recurrence relation:

 Let $u_{(x,y)}$ Be Bob's expected score if there are $y$ 1's remaining out of $x$ bits.

 If all the remaining bits have the same value, then Bob can score all of them by guessing that value.
$u_{(x,0)} = x$
$u_{(x,x)} = x$
 Otherwise, Bob's score can be determined recursively as the total of his expected score on a success and his expected score on a failure. The expected scores can be computed recursively.
$u_{(x,y)} = p_{success} * (u_{(x-1,y-1)} + 1) + p_{failure} * u_{(x-1, y)} | \frac{x}2 > y$
$u_{(x,y)} = p_{success} * (u_{(x-1,y)} + 1) + p_{failure} * u_{(x-1, y-1)} | \frac{x}2 \leq y$

We can evaluate this recurrence relation using a computer, from the bottom up - e.g. evaluating at $(0,0)$ first and then building up (computing it recursively from the top down, without storing previously computed values, would take 2^100 iterations).
The critical values are

 $u_{(100,41)}$ is 60.792, which is more than 60.
$u_{(100,42)}$ is 59.988, which is less than 60.


Here is a C# program which calculates the score at each value.
static double[,] CreateScoresTable(int maxValue)
{
    var size = maxValue + 1;
    var scores = new double[size, size];

    scores[0, 0] = 0;

    // Paint the edges
    for (int remainingGuesses = 0; remainingGuesses < size; remainingGuesses++)
    {
        // All false
        scores[remainingGuesses, 0] = remainingGuesses;

        // All true
        scores[remainingGuesses, remainingGuesses] = remainingGuesses;
    }

    // Fill in the middle
    for (int remainingGuesses = 2; remainingGuesses < size; remainingGuesses++)
    {
        for (int remainingTrueBits = 1; remainingTrueBits < remainingGuesses; remainingTrueBits++)
        {
            double scoreFromSuccess, scoreFromFailure;
            if (remainingTrueBits > remainingGuesses / 2)
            {
                // Should guess true
                var probabilityOfSuccess = (double)remainingTrueBits / remainingGuesses;

                scoreFromSuccess = probabilityOfSuccess * (1 + scores[remainingGuesses - 1, remainingTrueBits - 1]);
                scoreFromFailure = (1-probabilityOfSuccess) * scores[remainingGuesses - 1, remainingTrueBits];
            }
            else
            {
                // Should guess false
                var probabilityOfSuccess = 1 - ((double)remainingTrueBits / remainingGuesses);

                scoreFromSuccess = probabilityOfSuccess * (1 + scores[remainingGuesses - 1, remainingTrueBits]);
                scoreFromFailure = (1 - probabilityOfSuccess) * scores[remainingGuesses - 1, remainingTrueBits - 1];
            }

            scores[remainingGuesses, remainingTrueBits] = scoreFromSuccess + scoreFromFailure;
        }
    }

    return scores;
}


I am interested to know which computer evaluation tool you used (I programmed in Julia) and, of course, a mathematical proof would be better, perhaps I will one day  bounty for it

So this is the question to life, the universe and everything!

@FirstNameLastName - I wrote a C# program. I will add the code to my answer.

@TimC : upon re-reading answer : isn't smallest number the one with just 42 1's to the right i.e.: $2^{42}-1$?

@FirstNameLastName - You're right. Fixed.

@TimC nitpick ... also : 'no more than' should be 'no less than' :)

@TimC : I had calculated and programmed using recursion. Turns out I used recursion formula of MSE questions #614468

So Alice chooses from numbers where Bob can on average guess more than 60% of the digits, but as little more than 60% as possible. Alice should chose numbers with

 39 1's and 61 0's.

When she tells Bob how many 1's there are, his best strategy will be to choose

 0 almost every time, as each digit is more likely to be a 0 than a 1. In practice, Bob should choose 0 or 1 at each stage, depending on whether there are more 0's or 1's left in the remaining unknown digits.

The smallest such number is

 2^39-1 = 549,755,813,887


According to my Monte-Carlo simulations, this is probably incorrect. The average score for Bob given 39 1's and the strategy you describe is 62.47, with a margin of error of 0.006 The Monte Carlo seems to say that 42 1's is the best Alice can do, (with Bob scoring 59.99 and a 0.006 margin of error), but I don't know how to prove it mathematically.

@Tim C 42 1's maybe too many as Alice has to offer Bob more than 60%

@Tim C - but I don't doubt that my answer might not be a little out as it was a quick back of the envelope calculation.

@Penguino, Alice tells Bob "you can, on average, correctly guess almost 60% of the bit values" (emphasis added). That is, the expected number of correct guesses for the optimum strategy is less than 60, not greater than 60.  The final paragraph of the puzzle confirms this interpretation: the wanted number is one for which the expected number of correct guesses does not exceed 60.

@Penguino : your 'in practice' strategy for Bob is certainly correct! but the average assumption not.

After sufficient time I decided to un-delete own code :)
This isn't an official answer to the question, but rather its intent is to compliment Tim C's approved answer ... no need to down or up -vote ... up/down to you :)
Here is the program and recursive algorithm I coded in Julia:
(as I only recently happened to learn, it is the MSE question #614468 algorithm)
# is result already in cache ?
function iscached(cache, result)
    return haskey(cache, result)
end

# nm cache dictionary
# avoid potential order 2^(n+m) invocations
NM = Dict()
# nm recursively counts average number of correct bit value guesses
# given n bits 1 and m bits 0 (or the other way around)
# we compute using (big) rationals to find exact numbers
function nm(n, m)
    result = 0 // 1

    if iscached(NM, (n, m))
        result = NM[(n, m)]
    else
        # the following if's are mutually exclusive
        # there is really no particular good reason for this
        # apart maybe to make it easier to add debug prints for result

        # consider 2 cases 0

        if m > n == 0
            # all remaining guesses are correct
            result = m // 1
        end

        if n > m == 0
            # all remaining guesses are correct
            result = n // 1
        end

        # recurse: guess one value
        # and weigh remaining (one less) values

        # consider 3 cases > < =

        sum = (n + m) // 1

        # note > 0
        if n > m > 0
            # choose most likely
            probability = n // sum
            result = probability +
                probability * nm(n - 1, m) +
                (1 - probability) * nm(n, m - 1)
        end

        # note > 0
        if m > n > 0
            # choose most likely
            probability = m // sum
            result = probability +
                (1 - probability) * nm(n - 1, m) +
                probability * nm(n, m - 1)
        end

        # note > 0
        if n == m > 0
            # choose any (equal likely)
            probability = 1 // 2
            result = probability +
                probability * nm(n - 1, m) +
                probability * nm(n, m - 1)
        end
    end

    return NM[(n, m)] = result
end

N = big(100)

for n in 0 : N
    # this is not a loop :)
    for m in N - n : N - n
        print("$(n + m) ($n, $m) ")
        result = nm(n, m)
        print(Float64(result))
        print(" = $result")
        println()
    end
end

exit(0)

The tie break output (corresponding to given answer) is :
100 (41, 59) 60.7924151206883 = 6114634921008473035429070497//100582201066849840253175876
100 (42, 58) 59.98782093337133 = 8475921831768328808991723205//141294044355812870831842302

and symmetrically:
100 (58, 42) 59.98782093337133 = 8475921831768328808991723205//141294044355812870831842302
100 (59, 41) 60.7924151206883 = 6114634921008473035429070497//100582201066849840253175876

I have tried to come up with a mathematical formula to express the average but failed.
Whoever does succeed, I guess, deserves our admiration.
